# after setup theme action creating issue with nonce in wordpress 4.3.1

Tags: wordpress, nonce

I am using add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' ); hook in one of my website for auto redirect user to his dashboard page.
Here is my code :---

```
 function custom_login($username, $password='') {
 $creds = array();
 $creds['user_login'] = $username;
 $creds['user_password'] = $password;
 $creds['remember'] = true;
 $user = wp_signon( $creds, false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) ){
 echo $user->get_error_message();
}
}
// run it before the headers and cookies are sent
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'custom_login' );
```

Its working fine on old version, But now I have upgrade wordpress version and its creating problem with nonce.
Are you sure you want to do this?
Everytime this error display on the screen when I do anything like update plugin, theme and permalinks.

When I comment this code then website working fine except auto redirect functionality.
Here is my website url :- https://www.linearrecruitment.co.uk/

Please help me where I do mistake.

Answer (score 1):

That's a normal behaviour - [nonce](https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Nonces) is a token used by Wordpress to check the validity of the form in order to [prevent CSRF attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

A valid login form in Wordpress should have an hidden input field generated with [`wp_nonce_field`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nonce_field):

```
wp_nonce_field('my_login_form');
```

Then in the login function the token is checked with the [`wp_verify_nonce`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_verify_nonce) function:

```
if (!isset($_POST['my_login_form']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'my_login_form')) {
  die('Invalid form');
}
```

What you're trying to do (auto login) is done wrong as `add_action` doesn't send any parameter for the [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) hook, so your username is probably empty. I don't know how this could possibly work before, maybe it managed to log in somehow with an empty username.

I suggest you to declare some globals vars for your username and password, as it seems to be static inputs:

```
global $username, $password;
$username = 'my_login';
$password = 'my_password';
```

And then on the beginning of your function import those globals with:

```
global $username, $password;
```

### So what about the nonce?

On the last versions of Wordpress, the `check_admin_referer` have changed a bit, from:

```
function check_admin_referer( $action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce' ) {
    if ( -1 == $action )
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'You should specify a nonce action to be verified by using the first parameter.' ), '3.2' );

    $adminurl = strtolower(admin_url());
    $referer = strtolower(wp_get_referer());
    $result = isset($_REQUEST[$query_arg]) ? wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$query_arg], $action) : false;
    if ( !$result && !(-1 == $action && strpos($referer, $adminurl) === 0) ) {
        wp_nonce_ays($action);
        die();
    }
    do_action( 'check_admin_referer', $action, $result );
    return $result;
}
```

To :

```
function check_admin_referer( $action = -1, $query_arg = '_wpnonce' ) {
    if ( -1 == $action )
        _doing_it_wrong( __FUNCTION__, __( 'You should specify a nonce action to be verified by using the first parameter.' ), '3.2' );

    $adminurl = strtolower(admin_url());
    $referer = strtolower(wp_get_referer());
    $result = isset($_REQUEST[$query_arg]) ? wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST[$query_arg], $action) : false;
    do_action( 'check_admin_referer', $action, $result );

    if ( ! $result && ! ( -1 == $action && strpos( $referer, $adminurl ) === 0 ) ) {
        wp_nonce_ays( $action );
        die();
    }

    return $result;
}
```

As you can see they moved the `check_admin_referer` hook - now we can change the value of `$result` *before* the `wp_nonce_ays` function (the one that display the message you try to get rid of) as been called.

That mean we could add the following hook in the theme *functions.php* in order to force the nonce validation:

```
add_action( 'check_admin_referer', array('custom_check_admin_referer' ) );
function custom_check_admin_referer() {
    return 1;
}
```

That should work around your problem, but you must be aware that this could possibly be a security issue - you maybe want to do more test in that function before returning 1.